# Pyspark explode nested json - empty rows removed

Tags: json, pyspark

I have succesfully flattened a bunch of jsons with the following schema
[image]

using the following code:

```
feed_df = feed.select( "animal_uuid","timestamp", "total_fed", "total_visits",
explode("feed_part_totals").alias("feed_part_totalsExplode")
).select("animal_uuid","timestamp", "total_fed", "total_visits", "feed_part_totalsExplode.*")
```

I noticed that my flattened df has less rows than my nested df. It appears that rows that have no value in the nested feed_part_totals column are removed entirely.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: change explode to explode_outer and empty rows will be represented as null values.